# ggplot fill color issue png

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, fill

Why is the fill color not correctly saved when saving plot in png.
See the difference between pdf and png.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(f1=sample(c("a","b"),100,replace=T),
                 value=rnorm(100))
ggplot(df,aes(x=f1,y=value)) + geom_boxplot(fill="blue") 
ggsave("Boxplot.png")
ggsave("Boxplot.pdf")
```

[image]